# Setting divs next to each other

Tags: css, wordpress, html, css-float

I'm trying to place my 3 divs with the id = #boxes1, #boxes2, #boxes3 next to each other. For some reason the #boxes3 drops below #boxes2. The container I have should be large enough for it to not move down. I know it's suppose to "float: left;" but I am now lost as to why it's dropping down.

This is my loop.php from Wordpress http://pastebin.com/uh00RT8v
This is CSS http://pastebin.com/FU3tqbRM

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the rendered HTML with the CSS, preferably in a jsfiddle?  That will help sort it out quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've missed the end tag of your `<div id="boxes2">`. So it isn't rendered properly.

```
<div id="boxes2">
    <!--So lets set our category to only show technology-->
    <?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=9'); ?>
    <!--Start the loop-->
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <!--Inside the loop-->
        <div class="box">
            <!--The post title-->
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <!--The post image-->
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('homepage-thumb', array('alt' => '', 'title' => '')); ?></a>
        </div>  
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div> <!-- <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< This one -->
<?php rewind_posts(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your answers using firebug. Its an awesome web development plugin for browsers like firefox and chrome. And show the page where you have implmented it so that more halp can be provided. Hope it helps :)